# SELECT query to print as JSON list in one row

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

How to print names in string list in a single row?

Suppose that I have data like this:

```
SELECT XName FROM X_Table --(table has other columns too)

XName
-------------
Foo
Bar
```

How to get values like this:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: @G.Stoynev I checked your duplicate question suggestion, but I'm unable to get all the result in one single row, any help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example given in G.Stoynev link, you can do the following:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY
(
    (
        SELECT JSON_QUERY
        (
            '[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + convert(varchar(10), XName) + '"' 
            FROM dbo.X_Table
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' 
        ) Categories  
        FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
    ), '$.Categories' 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking at combination of JSON conversion and de-conversion syntax like below

<kbd>**[See working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=785fe0c47c2c9d3392fa4ffe852bc618)**</kbd>

```
Declare @js nvarchar(max)

SET @js= (SELECT XName FROM X_Table for json path)

select * from  OPENJSON (@js) WITH ( Xname nvarchar(max) N'$.XName')
```

And if you want to avoid using a variable @js you can do

```
select * from  OPENJSON 
((SELECT XName FROM XTable for json path))-- note double parenthesis
WITH ( Xname nvarchar(max) N'$.XName')
```